# wordpress adnimistration page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Anyone know of a site that explains how WordPress created its appearances in WordPress (on the backend) I like how the navigation was created and I am trying to drill down to see what makes it tick but its a heck of a mess of code. Has anyone launched anything online that you know of explaining how these pieces were made? Maybe something cleaner.

Comment: You are wanting to understand the interface (HTML/CSS) or how to add your own plug-in to the Wordpress admin?

Comment: I would suggest reading up on basic HTML/CSS interface design and jQuery powered AJAX interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you are thinking about all the effects - collapsable menus, toggleable sidebar and draggable secions at the dashboard, you should really take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/). These frameworks will make a lot of this interaction really, really simple.

Comment: also extjs(extjs.com) theres even a php library around